# Backlink check script PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I got a script to check if a URL is present in a page. Here it is:

```
  class LP_backlinkchecker
  {
  var $url;
  var $content;
  var $links;
  var $linktocheck;

 function __construct($url, $linktocheck)
 {
 $this->url = $url;
 $this->linktocheck = $linktocheck;
 }

 function SetLinktocheck($link)
 {
 $this->linktocheck = $link;
 } 


function getContents()
{
$this->content = file_get_contents($this->url);
} 


function lpFetchLinks()
{
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $this->content, $matches);
$this->links = $matches;
return $matches;
}


function check()
{
 foreach($this->links[2] as $key => $url)
   {
    if($url == $this->linktocheck)return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;  
   }

 }
```

My problem is that the script only works for checking links on the same site. It does not work when the links to check is outside of the website. For example, the script works well to check the link
http://web.com/linktocheck present on the website http://web.com/

If think my $regexp is wrong, do you have some idea of the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why such a difficult regex if you only want to check if a link is present?

Comment: To be honest I got this script from a colleague .. I don't know

Comment: What kind of regex would you do ? Because i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have misunderstood your issue but your code seems to work for me. I wrote you a little unit test that you can now have and expand upon, if you could write a test that does not work I might be able to help more.

```
class LP_backlinkcheckerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $l;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->l = new LP_backlinkchecker('test.html', null);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
    }

    public function testGetContents()
    {
        $this->l->getContents();
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->l->content);
    }

    public function testlpFetchLinks()
    {
        $this->l->getContents();
        $matches = $this->l->lpFetchLinks();

        $expected = array(
            "http://google.com",
            "http://www.bluesnews.com",
            "http://www.bluesnews.com/somepage"
        );

        // 4 things captured by the regex
        $this->assertEquals(4, count($matches));
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $matches[2]);
    }
}
```

and the HTML file I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.bluesnews.com">BluesNews.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.bluesnews.com/somepage">somepage</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Although it would be better to make your class so that I don't have to supply it a file but that's the way you designed it. I would also suggest perhaps using parse_url to breakdown the url into it's component parts. Your problem may be just that your expecting one string to be equal to the other and there may be a user input error at construct time which your not checking at all.

Comment: It's to hard for me !
I'm looking for the right regex to check if a link is present

Comment: I'm telling you it works, or at least your regex works, show us how you are calling the class?

Comment: $BCHECK = new LP_backlinkchecker($url, $linktocheck);
$BCHECK->getContents();
$BCHECK->lpFetchLinks();

Comment: I don't know why link detection don't work when a link on a page go in an over website

Comment: If you see the HTML page I pasted above you see that all three links go to a url which is on another site. The test I wrote proves that the three links that come back as expected so it's NOT your regex as far as I can tell unless there is something different about your content. You can also maybe make your life easier (no regex) and use a DOM Parser to pull out the url's